# Angular click event doesn't work in dynamic list

Tags: angular, events, click, angular-changedetection

Apparently Angular is not detecting the "Click" event. I am using "Swiper" as the base library to create a carousel in Stenciljs. Regarding the tests I have done in the code, apparently the problem is with Angular, because if my carousel, for example, has 5 elements, the first three elements can be seen in the first view, when we go to the next group of elements, those, those no longer have the "click" event listening on Angular.

**(I will skip left and right arrows)**

**component.html**

```html
<fd-slide class="slide-banner" *ngFor="let item of items">
   <div>
     <button (click)="clickMe()">Click Me!</button>
   </div>
</fd-slide>
```

**component.ts**

```js
clickMe() {
  console.log('listening for click event');
 }
```

Obviously, "items" is an array that is obtained by a request to an endpoint, which I consume in the hook `"ngAfterViewInit"` like this:

**I omit logic here because it would be very extensive, but the data arrives complete**

```js
ngAfterViewInit () {
   this.myService.subscribe (data => {
     this.items = data;
     this.cdf.detectChanges (); // I have also used markForCheck ()
   });
}
```

[image]

You can see an animation of my problem:

https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-7310a6ff55b7.gif

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try subscribing to your data in the `ngOnInit` hook instead? I would think you would want your data to load *before* the component view is rendered in order for all of your slides to instantiate accordingly.

Comment: No, because I need to pass data configuration to the carousel component and if the content is not loaded yet (`ngOnInit`) that object doesn't work.

Comment: which npm package you have used for swiper ? or can you share a demo of your problem in stackblitz ?

Comment: Actually, I tried to summarize the problem because we are using a SAP adaptation for Angular called Spartacus (on the one hand), but we are consuming components made in Stenciljs. The problem is that the first three "slides" of the carousel work well, but the following ones do not accept the click, it seems that the event was being canceled.

Comment: @LogicBlower to upload an example to StackBlitz I would have to adapt the project made in stenciljs, because it is a private project in the company where I work, I can't upload the project.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could provide more of your code in-order to troubleshoot this issue, but given what you have above, i would suggest you try subscribing to your data in the `ngOnInit` life cycle hook which executes before the view is rendered and in addition, use a boolean property to track when that data has loaded. Then, reference that boolean in your template using the `ngIf` directive to restrict the `fd-slide` component from rendering until the data has loaded like so:

component ts:

```
slideDataHasLoaded:boolean = false;

clickMe() {
 console.log('listening for click event');
}

ngOnInit () {
   this.myService.subscribe (data => {
     this.items = data;
     this.slideDataHasLoaded = true; // <-- set the boolean to true here
     this.cdf.detectChanges();
   });
}
```

template html:

```
<div class="fd-slide-wrapper" *ngIf="slideDataHasLoaded">
  <fd-slide class="slide-banner" *ngFor="let item of items">
   <div>
     <button (click)="clickMe()">Click Me!</button>
   </div>
  </fd-slide>
</div>
```

Given that i am adding a wrapping div here to your template, you may need to write some additional css to accommodate and/or correct the layout.